# How to disable notification for indicator-keylock?

Tags: notification

I have installed `indicator-keylock`  and notifications are really annoying , menubar icon is more than enough ?

is there a way to disable this specific app notifications

Answer (score 0):

[dconf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/dconf.1.html) and its write parameter alows you to turn that off with:

```
dconf write /apps/indicators/keylock/notifications false
```